# Github Actions running both .Net Core and Ant Design Pro

Tags: cypress, github-actions, ant-design-pro

I want to be able to run both .NET core and ant design pro (React) using Cypress Github Actions but however, I have the problem below:

Problem:

1. Error message: AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: `.ant-pro-table-list-toolbar-right > :nth-child(1) > .ant-space > [style=""] > .ant-btn`, but never found it.

It was running smoothly on localhost but couldn't work on github actions. Steps that I took to run locally:

1. type "dotnet run"
2. type "yarn start"

and it is able to run locally.

cypress.js

```
describe('test button', () => {
it('Create application',() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:8000/Application')
    cy.get('.ant-pro-table-list-toolbar-right > :nth-child(1) > .ant-space > [style=""] > .ant-btn').click()
}
```

main.yml

```
name: Cypress

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  Build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        working-directory: dotnet
        dotnet-version: 5.0.404
        run: dotnet run --no-restore
  

    - name: Cypress tests
      uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
      with:
        working-directory: my-app
        browser: chrome
        record: true
        build: yarn run build
        start: yarn start
        wait-on: 'http://localhost:8000'
      env:
        CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
        DEBUG: "@cypress/github-action"
```

Hope to have someone to help.